# Java garbage collection and memory issues

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, hash, garbage-collection

I'm developing a chessbot and the only memory intensive operation is hashing evaluated board positions. As part of testing changes, I make the bot play lots of consecutive games against another bot. I'm experiencing erratic behavior whenever memory use hovers around 2GB (which is a memory limit I've set in Netbeans). When I turn off hashing and memory use drops to very low levels, these problems disappear.

Another, possible related symptom is that as it plays more consecutive games, it uses more and more memory. I initialize a new instance of the AI between games and all the references to the previous instance, its HashMap and their contents are lost. Java Garbage Collection should be able to clean these objects, but it looks like it's not able to clear all of them.

I'm failling to understand what is happening. In particular,

- Why am I not getting any errors, notifications or warnings about reaching the memory limit?
- When the memory limit is reached, I would expect the program to slow down. Instead, it's just making erratic decisions, as if it's pulling invalid values from the HashMap.
- With regards to increasing memory use in consecutive games, is Java's Garbage Collection working correctly?